# Mostrar Hora SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Tengo este codigo, como pueden ver se registra el Nombre de un trbajador, pero no se como mostrar esa hora en un `textView`, ya que si hago esto, `tvHora.setText(date);` no me muestra nada y se me cierra la app.

```
private String getDate() {             
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm  a", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);

    }

    public void guardar(){

        String Nombre = text.getText().toString();

        SQLite base = new SQLite( this,"SQLite",null,1 );
        SQLiteDatabase bd = base.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contenedor = new ContentValues();
        contenedor.put("NOMBRE", Nombre );
        contenedor.put( "FECHA",getDate() );

        try {
            bd.insertOrThrow("TRABAJADOR",null,contenedor);
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Ingresado Correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


        }catch (SQLException e){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"No Ingresado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


        }
        bd.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto ves todo el String (EEEE dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm  a):

```
tvHora.setText(getDate());
```

De esta otra forma verías, en ocasiones si, en otras no, solo la hora (hh:mm a):

```
tvHora.setText(getDate().substring(17, 25));
```

Esto porque van a variar el total de los caracteres(lunes tiene 5, miercoles 9...).
En este caso primero coloca la hora al guardarlo en SQlite (hh:mm a EEEE dd/MM/yyyy) y así los 
substrings serían 0-11 (incluidos los puntos de pm/am).

Otra forma es usar un nuevo SimpleDateFormat con el nuevo formato que quieres (hh:mm a) 
usando Calendar dentro de un try/catch:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");  // el nuevo formato que quieres
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                       // instancias el Calendar
String fecha = getDate();  // o la columna de tu base de datos
try {
      cal.setTime(formato.parse(fecha));                    
      tvHora.setText(formato.format(cal.getTime()));      // el textView dentro del try

} catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :) funciono muy bien!!! Si no es molestia tengo otro problemita, lo que pasa es que ese registro lo muestro en un ListView, pero cada vez que retrocedo o me salgo de la aplicacion el contenido del ListView se borra. Pero muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo bastante.

Comment: Pues realiza una nueva pregunta. Y no olvides mostrar código para que sea bien recibida